# Как обратиться к событию от унаследованого обьекта?

Tags: наследование

Нужно создать свой тип на основании типа `TShape`, сделал:

```
Type TOperation = class(tshape) 
private
 Opname:string;
 procedure Opcreate();
end;
```

Дальше по нажатию какой-нибудь кнопки этот объект будет создан на форме. Задаются ширина, высота, положение, в общем всё, что нужно для отображения этого потомка на форме. Отображается.

Дальше сам вопрос:

Как организовать его drag-and-drop? Хотя, как drag-and-drop работает я знаю, сама проблема в обращении к событию предка `OnMouseDown` и др.

Мы унаследовали объект `TShape`, как обратиться к его событиям?

Comment: вы хоть для приличия язык указали бы

Comment: по ходу это delphi. public и published свойства доступны без ограничений. в чем проблема и при чем тут d'n'd вообще непонятно.

Comment: Спасибо. Дейстфительно, прошу прощения.... Да, это делфи. Проблема... Я создаю свой обьект, который является потомком ТШейпа. Как после этого описать событие OnClick хотя бы? Если мы делаем это через конструктор оно само генерируется в тексте программы, остаётся только подсказать ему что делать при этом событии.

Comment: если я пишу вот так:

procedure Toperation.OnMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
flag:=true;
end;

он ругается что такой индентификатор не декларирован.

Comment: @SCHIP, а почему вы пишете TOperation.OnMouseDown? TOperation.OnMouseDown - это свойство объекта типа TMouseEvent. Если вы хотите повесить обработчик на mousemove это надо делать в форме `procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseMove(....)`, которая может быть назначена объекту `Op: TOperation;` в виде `Op.OnMouseMove:=Shape1MouseMove;` или в Object Inspectore (если у вас компонент установлен был в палитру...).